# Android Nullpointerexception and delete row from sqlite retun 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I write a simple APP with SQLite ADD and DELETE functions by long touch on the ListView item. But there are error when execute DELETE.

Logcat(solved)

```
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at tw.danny.idcc_hw2.savedHeadlinesFragment$1.onItemLongClick(savedHeadlinesFragment.java:91)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2921)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2871)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-17 21:19:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My APP is to use ListView fragment to display data(title) and longClick item to add it to database. In activity2, display all data(title) in database with the same layout. From now on, all functions works well. The problem appeared when I want to implement DELETE in activity2 with same operation as ADD in activity1.**

onItemLongClick Listener(activity2 for DELETE)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

            //Long press to delete article from db
            int rnumber =  dbHlp.DELETEColumData(RSSData.Headlines.get(position));

            if(rnumber==1)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else if(rnumber==0)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

onItemLongClick Listener(activity1 for ADD)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            //Long press to add article to db
            long rowID =  dbHlp.ADDColumData(RSSData.Headlines.get(position), RSSData.Articles.get(position));


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Add to list. id:"+rowID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Function in SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class RSSDBHlp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ReadLater";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "article";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                " id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                " title TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " detail TEXT );";

public RSSDBHlp(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}


public long ADDColumData(String Title,String Detail) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();      
    ContentValues values =new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", Title);
    values.put("detail", Detail);
    long rowID =db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    db.close();
    return rowID;
}

public int DELETEColumData(String Title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("MSG","DELETE:"+Title);
    String whereClause = "title='" + Title + "'";
    int rnumber = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, null);

    //0:error 1:all row delete

    db.close();
    return rnumber;
}
```

What's wrong with it, I only copy and modify some code upon ADD function which works well.

DELETE return

```
 Returns
the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.
```

Comment: Which line is it throwing the null pointer on?

Comment: make a log onitemlongclick to ensure getting title value correctly

Comment: have you done `DataBaseHelper dbHlp= new DataBaseHelper();//your database helper class`

Comment: @user2174595 could you please post your complete code?

Comment: I solved Nullpointerexception by initial DataBaseHelper. But DELETE function still can't delete row well(return 0)

Comment: I'm sure that onitemlongclick get the correct title value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NullPointerException**

You have not initialized the variable `dbHlp`. So its throwing `NullPointerException`.

Initialize `dbHlp` before you use it for the first time. i.e.,

`dbHlp = new RSSDBHlp();`

**delete row from sqllite return 0**

Modify the statements

```
String whereClause = "title='" + Title + "'";
int rnumber = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, null);
```

as below

```
int rnumber = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "title=?", new String[] {Title});
```

Comment: That's what it looks like to me, but can't tell without all of the code

Comment: thanks.The problem is this exactly. But there are still a problem described in comment of main article. Can you give me some suggestions

Comment: @user2174595 Are you passing the `title` value which is existing in the table? Please Log the value returned by the statement `RSSData.Headlines.get(position)`. It might be the problem

Comment: @user2174595 your function should really work dude. please add more logs or information which is helpful for us. We don't find any lines which adds the data to the table and there is no code to confirm that `RSSData.Headlines.get(position)` returns correct value

Comment: i just added the ADD function. Log RSSData.Headlines.get(position) is the same value as my longClick item (I delete the code above)

Comment: Thanks for your attention to answer my questions and this is worth the best answer. But the db.delete still return 0 after modified in your way. Tell me if any information i can give

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a debugging thing, looking at code without having it working is sometimes not as easy compared to having the debugger in front of you.

My best guess is, assuming you are 100% sure the dbHlp variable has been initialized, that RSSData.Headlines or RSSData is null. I would start debugging in this direction, however it is hard to help with a 100% useful answer with the information provided.

Regards

Comment: thanks.The problem is the initialization of the dbHlp. But there are still a problem described in comment of main article. Can you give me some suggestions